# Why is neutrality so important in a voltaic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of a salt bridge in a voltaic cell. I keep reading the same thing: without a salt bridge/porous cup, the anode will continue to lose mass and become aqueous cations, and the cathode will continue to gain mass and lose aqueous cations, building a negative charge at the cathode and a positive charge at the anode. The salt bridge is used to maintain neutrality.

What I don't understand is *why do we need to maintain neutrality?* Why would the cell stop running if the half-cells aren't neutral?

Comment: Without the salt bridge, only a very tiny and declining current initially flows. This creates a back-potential that opposes the current. So you would essentially have a pathetically small and leaky capacitor.

Comment: If you realize lightnings are caused by charge disbalance of typically just dozens of coulombs, you will get the picture why is charge balance important.

Comment: The bridge allow current to pass and this maintains neutrality would be more appropriate that maintain neutrality alone. This naturally resolves the question about the *cell* that otherwise stops.

Answer (score 11):

> without a salt bridge/porous cup, the anode will continue to lose mass
> and become aqueous cations, and the cathode will continue to gain mass
> and lose aqueous cations, building a negative charge at the cathode
> and a positive charge at the anode.

This is *totally* wrong. No current will flow without a salt bridge and electrolysis will not occur.

We sometimes undermine the effect of a build-up of small charges. Let us take an example from electrostatics. If you recall Van de Graaf generator which is popularly used to demonstrate air sparks and even electrification of hair in air etc. How much charge are we talking about? I quote one solved example from a physics website [here](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/19-3-electrical-potential-due-to-a-point-charge/).

> A demonstration Van de Graaff generator has a 25.0 cm diameter metal
> sphere that produces a voltage of **100 kV** near its surface. (See Figure
> 1.) What excess charge resides on the sphere?

Watch this video, if you are not familiar with Van de Graaf generator [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3tauzN6-Uk)

Now, 100,000 V is really high voltage. What is the charge on the sphere? It is only 1.39 $\mu$C. This sounds like a small charge but it corresponds to a lot of electrons. The moral of the story *is it is impossible to store even very small amounts of charges on objects* in air. The objects will try to get rid of excess charges as soon as possible. This is basically the reason that matter does not like charge imbalance, in other words charge neutrality is maintained in everyday life. Everyone hates the electric shock after touching a door knob in winter after walking on a carpet. The reason is same. Matter does not like charge build up. You are electrically charged and the moment we are close to a conductor, like a door knob, electron transfer takes place, which is often accompanied by a spark.

Now the voltage on an ordinary battery is nowhere near 100,000 Volts. Still, Nature does not allow the build up of charges on the electrodes due to a 1.5 V home battery. Coming to your thought experiment... Take two beakers with one electrode each, dipped in an electrolyte. There you connect the two electrodes to a battery with the help of wires. No current will flow in the solutions as well as the external circuit because the two beakers are placed apart, and current cannot pass through air easily (very high resistance). *When there is no current in the solution, there will be no electrolysis.*

What a salt bridge does is that it provides a flow path for current between two separate beakers. In other words, it allows the movement of charges (ions) from beaker to the other.

Just as a mental exercise, replace the salt bridge with a piece of copper wire whose each end dips in the two beakers? What do you expect will happen?

Comment: Just to put it another way, the charged van der Graaf generator in the example will have a charge imbalance measured in the range of parts per **trillion** (e.g., for every one trillion electrons with a counterbalancing proton, there will be only a handful of "extra" electrons or protons). For objects in more normal conditions, any macroscopic charge imbalance is multiple orders of magnitude smaller still.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that without a salt bridge electrolysis happens but due to charge build up it _very_ quickly slows down? Or would it be more correct to say it doesn't happen at all?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion, No it does not occur at all. The very very small current if it ever flows is polarization current just like a capacitor.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion If both half cells are physically separated, potential of their electrolytes would follow the potential of electrodes with some constant difference.

Answer (score -2):

Neutrality is necessary in all chemical operations occurring in aqueous phase, not only in voltaic cells. It is an experimental result.

Comment: I understand, but why?

Comment: @FouadSaffar The opposite charges of value that pass in 1 s at current 1 A, if 10 cm apart, are in water attracted by force equivalent to the weight of about 1 100 000 000 kg. That is why. In air, it would be even about 80 times more.